# Error instantiating a class in Python

Tags: python, function, class, dictionary, instantiation

I'm attempting to instantiate a class:

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, money, ownership):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.ownership = ownership

    def can_afford(self):
        x = False
        for bike in bikes.values():

            if self.money >= bike.money * margin:
                print "Customer {} can afford {}".format(self.name, bike)
                x = True
        if not x:
            print "Customer {} cannot afford any bikes at this time.".format(self.name)

shoppers = {        
    # Initial condition of shopper1
    "Jane": Customer("Jane", 200, False),
    # Initial condition of shopper2
    "Alfred": Customer("Alfred", 500, False),
    # Initial condition of shopper3
    "Taylor": Customer("Taylor", 1000, False)
}

buyer = Customer(name, money, ownership)
```

but `buyer = Customer(name, money, ownership)` keeps getting errored:

```
Undefined variable 'name'
Undefined variable 'money'
Undefined variable 'ownership'
```

But I thought I set the variable's values in my dictionary with "Customer(...)"

Comment: Yes you've set the basis for Jane, Alfred and Taylor. What is that separate "buyer" instantiation for and where are its values supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, money, ownership):
        self.name = name
        self.money = money
        self.ownership = ownership

    def can_afford(self):
        x = False
        for bike in bikes.values():

            if self.money >= bike.money * margin:
                print "Customer {} can afford {}".format(self.name, bike)
                x = True
        if not x:
            print "Customer {} cannot afford any bikes at this time.".format(self.name)

shoppers = {        
    # Initial condition of shopper1
    "Jane": Customer("Jane", 200, False),
    # Initial condition of shopper2
    "Alfred": Customer("Alfred", 500, False),
    # Initial condition of shopper3
    "Taylor": Customer("Taylor", 1000, False)
}
#this is solution for your MENTIONED problem only
name = 'Buddy' 
money = 2
ownership = 'something'
buyer = Customer(name, money, ownership)
```

Solution for your mentioned problem is above, you just need to define some values.
But there are some other issues as well, like bikes.values(), from where this came?

Remember, to use something, you have to first tell what it is, so define things.

Hope it helps.